# Netflix desktop not working

Tags: 14.04, netflix

Could someone help me with netflix on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.
`Pipelight` does not work. When I go to the netflix desktop application it opens firefox, and shows the series, but when I click to play a screen appears telling me:

```
You're almost ready and only need to install the microsoft silverlight plugin.
```

Pipelight itself is installed and enabled but I saw in the window on the desktop opens netflix portion plugins complements the pipelight appears with this error

```
Pipelight Error (silverlight5.1)!
Something went wrong, check the terminal output
libpipelight-silverlight5.1.so
application/x-pipelight-error-silverlight5.1  
(Error during initialization: pipelighterror-silverlight5.1)
```

If I open Firefox by other plugins and see the pipelight okay, this error does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully enabled netflix desktop with a customized wine version from:

http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html

You will need to enable silverlight before start wine-browser
Use two commands:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
pipelight-plugin --update
```

For some reason the first command was not enough, I have started wine-browser before ran it, and I had to remove the .wine-browser folder with:

```
rm -rf .wine-browser
```

And then I ran it without any problem. (silverlight plugin).

There is also: [A way to enable netflix-desktop using pipelight](http://bitelia.com/2014/01/como-utilizar-netflix-linux)

With commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

It seems to install a shortcut to the application so you just have to call Netflix from your dash or alt+f2 (krunner), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-installing Pipelight. I used the following commands to install and update:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

Now enable silverlight plugin

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

the netflix app should work now. 
Also i has observed the same error where it asks to install silverlight even after enabling it using Pipelight. I rebooted ubuntu, this kicked in the silverlight and then the app works fine.